# Interpreting output after using callback in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, callback, functional-programming

I am new to javascript and I am trying to understand callbacks. I am not able to understand why 20 is getting printed before 10. My understanding is for a callback function like - `func1(parameter,func2())` , `func2()` is the callback function, which gets executed after `func1` executes with the "parameter" passed to `func1`. Is my understanding correct?

```
function timePass(length){

    console.log("finished after doing timePass for "+length +" seconds")
}

timePass(10,timePass(20));
```

OUTPUT BELOW:

> finished after doing timePass for 20 seconds
>
> finished after doing timePass for 10 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you **execute** the function `timePass` and then - adding the result as argument number 2.

Explaining what is happening:

First you define new function "timePass", The function printing on the console.
Second you execute `timePass(10, /*But here you execute it again*/ timePass(20))`.

The function timePass(20) will be executed first because you added `()`.
`() == execute`. If you just pass the name of the function, it will be passed as function. When you use `()` it will be executed and then the result will be passed as argument.

## EXAMPLE OF USING CALLBACK

```
function timePass(length, callbackFunction){

    console.log("finished after doing timePass for "+length +" seconds");

    // check if the function caller is included callback parameter
    // and check if it is function - to prevent errors.
    if (callbackFunction && typeof callbackFunction == "function") {
        // Execute the callback (timePass)
        callbackFunction(20);
    }
}

// Here you say, Execute timePass with arg 10, and then call timePass
timePass(10, timePass);
// and now callbackFunction defined above will be == timePass

// You can do also
timePass(10, anotherFunction)
// So another function will be executed after console.log()
```

**USE CASES**

Most often callbacks are used while we working with async code.

For example: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x03zf40z/)

```
// Imagine we have function which will request the server for some data.
function getData(index) {
  // The request - response will took some time
  // 0.1s ? 15s ? We don't know how big is the data we downloading.
  var data;
  // Imagine this is an AJAX call, not timeout.
  setTimeout(function() {
    // after 30ms we recieved 'server data'
    data = 'server data';
  },30)

  return data;
}

var users = getData('users');

console.log(users); // undefined - because we returned "data" before the AJAX is completed.

/*
So we can change the function and adding an callback.
*/

function getAsyncData(index, callback) {
  var data;
  // Imagine this is an AJAX call, not timeout.
  setTimeout(function() {
    // after 30ms we recieved 'server data'
    data = 'server data';
    callback(data);
  },30)

}

getAsyncData('users', function(data) {
  console.log(data); // 'server data'
});

// OR

function processData(data) {
  console.log(data);
}

getAsyncData('users', processData); // processData also logs 'server data'
```

Comment: so it is just a way of passing a block of statements or function to another function . I can use this function passed to do things accordingly within the body. The only advantage here I see is that I can pass different functions into the callback as per my needs. Am I right?

Comment: The callbacks are used most often with async code. When you reading some file or downloading a data from DB server, it tooks some time. So you must "wait" for it before continue, right? So you can use callback function to do some work after the async code is done. If you want I will explain the "use cases" in an edit.

Comment: The above example that you gave does not look asynchronous because the callback is getting executed only at the end of the parent method. Can you give example of an async callback ? Thanks

Comment: I just read this - https://blog.engineyard.com/2015/taming-asynchronous-javascript-with-async . It seems that callbacks are a way to make sure that asynchronous functions which are dependent on each other work well. Callback is a way to ensure that before you invoke a function, its parent or function on which it is dependent has been completed.

Answer (score 4):

You are not really creating a callback function but actually calling timePass(20) before everything else on your last line of code.

To pass a callback function you should do something like this:

```
function timePass(length,callback){
    console.log("finished after doing timePass for "+length +" seconds")
    if(typeof(callback) == "function")
        callback(20);
}

timePass(10,timePass);
```

Comment: I love your use of `callback && callback()` to prevent massive recursion

Comment: what does that line do ? callback && callback()

Comment: when will the left hand side evaluate to false?

Comment: @Zack yes i was writing a different example so it's not really needed. You can check if the callback exists instead as in my updated code.

Comment: Okay. In what scenario do we use "callback && callback()" ?

Comment: @Zack It's used to execute the callback only when it's defined and not 0 or false or null (it's truth-y)

Answer (score 2):

basically when the interpreter is looking at this, it will call `timepass(20)` to evaluate the result (which is nothing as you have no return returning something), which then it tries to pass into the outer function.

i.e.

```
doFunction( doSomethingElse() );
```

if `doSomethingElse` returns 1, it must evaluate that before it can pass that 1 into `doFunction`.

Fundamentally, you have not actually passed a callback, you have *called* the function. Perhaps you meant:

```
callback = function() { somecode; }
target = function(data, callback) { console.log('hi'); callback(); }

target(10, callback);
```

notice the lack of `()` i.e. `callback` not `callback()`

Comment: is it mandatory to have second argument in target method definition?

Comment: no not at all - you can have as many arguments as you like. If you want the callback then you need to have an argument to pass it in.  These functions aren't really asynchronous yet though - if you were to do something like UI animations etc, thats when you want to use callbacks to make sure it all works fine. Its hard to advise without more context on what you're trying to do.

Comment: also be wary of passing a the same function into itself as a callback - you can end up with a recursive thing, which is cool, but generally bad programming (its complicated and to do with overflowing the stack) - while recursion is a handy concept, you can do the same thing with a good loop.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html If you consider the ec2.acceptVpcPeeringConnection method on this page, it is accepting params. So there must be a callback(); within the body of the method so that the function() that I am passing gets executed before the acceptVpcPeeringConnection passes control back to the caller?

Comment: Im a little unsure of your exact example. Note in their examples they are taking a function definiton, not a function pointer - so theres a difference between saying target(10, callback) and target(10, foo(x,y) { ... } ); The latter doesn't call it as its a function definition (i.e. that  foo() {} effecivly returns a function reference itself).